# Health cloud exception : System.TypeException: duplicate field selected: HealthCloudGA__Gender__c

Tags: exception, health-cloud

> 17:03:45.999 (4002819908)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[435]|System.DmlException:
> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q3N000004BCH1UAO;
> first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record
> because the “Lead To Patient Conversion” process failed. Give your
> Salesforce admin these details. An Apex error occurred:
> System.TypeException: duplicate field selected:
> HealthCloudGA__Gender__c

Addtional Information:

- `Lead To Patient Conversion` flow is coming from salesforce health
  cloud package.
- `HealthCloudGA__Gender__c` - this field is from health cloud package. The field is present on lead object.
- Whenever we try to convert the lead by using standard `Convert to Patient`button(part of health cloud managed package.) we are facing the above issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what have you done/investigated? Has the button ever worked before? Have you changed anything recently - lead field mappings?

Comment: I've reopened this question based on the finding that this is a Salesforce bug with a detailed answer (below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a similar scenario I've seen in the past, if you create a custom field that shares the same API name with a packaged field, it could potentially cause problems in flows, processes, or triggers that use either of these fields.

Please check if you have any custom field with API name as Gender__c in your org and try to delete/rename it. While lead conversion is occurring, it evaluates by adding a prefix on the gender field and as per the managed package, it would be HealthCloudGA_Gender__c again resulting in the duplicate error.

Best practice recommendation is to keep custom field names unique.

Note: Our salesforce team filed bug #W-7717592 to address this behavior.

**UPDATE:**
The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=prerequisites_before_installation.htm&type=5&language=en_US) has been updated to reflect this point

> When creating custom fields or objects, don’t use the same API names as any packaged objects or fields. If you use the same names, the custom fields or objects can interfere with flows, processes, and triggers in Health Cloud.

Comment: thanks for the help. This workes well.